How can I generate a mu symbol when using markdown to add text to a Shiny app?
I am building a Shiny app with R, and there is a fair amount of text, so I am using markdown to store that text and render it in Shiny with the function includeMarkdown
I've found information on how to render symbols in Rmarkdown, and knitting a document; or in Shiny when writing the code in the ui.R script.  But it doesn't seem to work to get the symbols from a markdown document (.md) displayed in a Shiny app.
Reproducible code:
ui <- fluidPage(p(includeMarkdown("text/page-1-about.md")))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

This is what I have entered in my .md file:
This should show a mu symbol.
This should show a $\mu$ symbol.
This should show a symbol("mu")
None of them display the symbol.

Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61758316/how-to-use-includemarkdown-to-create-about-help-page-in-a-shiny-app. Your example is not reproducible as you haven’t provided your markdown file.

Sorry I don't know how to add a .md file.

Try any the following:
if just in R,
library(shiny)
library(htmltools) 

HTML("\u00b5")
tags$pre("µ")
xml2::url_unescape("\u00b5")


if in R markdown
$\mu$

$$\mu$$

This worked for me, this is done outside the R chunk where you put regular text This would be an inline mu sign here: $\mu$
